# How Can I View the Files Synced Since a Given Date in P4?

Tags: perforce

So, I'm trying to troubleshoot an error, and being able to see what files were synced to a given server since a certain date would go a long way toward helping me figure things out. I feel like there should be a way to do this through "p4 have", but I can't figure it out or find it in the documentation.

Important: I am NOT looking for what files were submitted into p4 during that time. I only want to see what files were synced to this server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"p4 have" will indeed tell you what files are currently sync'd to this workspace. But it won't tell you **when** they were sync'd. This sounds like one of those questions where if you told us a little bit about **why** you thought you wanted to know this information, we could probably suggest a different technique, which would address your problem.

Comment: Wow, blast from the past. I asked this 7 months ago, so I barely even remember why I asked. I think the reason I wanted to know is because we noticed a bug that began on a certain date, so we wanted to see which files had been synced to the server on that date, and which ones were synced afterwards, so we could have some idea of which files would likely have caused the error.

Comment: I often use date ranges on my revision specs for this purpose. For example, 'p4 changes //...@2011/04/28,@2011/04/29' to look at all the changes submitted on a certain day. A similar syntax can be used on 'p4 files', etc.